# Get JavaScript object from array by choosing one of multiple properties values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, filter

I know similar questions have been asked before, but this one is a bit different.

I have this **JS** *Array*:

```
var Array = [{
    name: "Name1",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t1", "t2", "t3"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t2", "t4"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Name3",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t1", "t3", "t4"
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to choose an object from the array where it has a `"t1"` IN `tags` in this `Search()` function

```
function Search(e){
    for(const obj of Array){
        if (*A SORTING WAY*) {
            obj.show = true
        } else {
            obj.show = false
        }
    }
    Render()
}
```

The `Render()` Function is:

```
function Render(){
    const app = document.getElementById('app')
    app.innerHTML =''
    for (const objIndex in Array) {
        const obj = Array[objIndex]
        const ob = document.createElement('div')
        ob.classList.add('class','col')
        ob.innerHTML = '<p>' + obj.name + '</p> <img src="assets/'+ obj.src +'.png"></img>'
        if (obj.show) {
            app.append(ob)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code/efforts then only we can help you.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I have added my code. I hope you can help me

Answer (score 1):

`Array.filter()` would do that

```js
var array = [{
    name: "Name1",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t1", "t2", "t3"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t2", "t4"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Name3",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t1", "t3", "t4"
    ]
  }
];

console.log(array.filter((v) => v.tags.includes("t1")));
```

Edit: replaced the use of `indexOf` with `includes`

Comment: Why not use `includes` instead of `indexOf`?

Comment: just out of habit i suppose, but `includes` would work fine also, it looks more readable too. I'll update it, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code in Javascript:

```
var Array1 = [{
    name: "Name1",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t1", "t2", "t3"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Name2",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t2", "t4"
    ]
  },
  {
    name: "Name3",
    src: "Source",
    tags: [
      "t1", "t3", "t4"
    ]
  }
]

var array2 = [];
Array1.find(function(e){
   if(e.tags.includes("t1")){
array2.push(e)
  }
})
```